# SQL: Running total count of distinct values

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, aggregate-functions, cumulative-sum

I'm trying to obtain rolling number of unique values in a window.

Here's how my table looks like:

```
SELECT 
   user_id
   , order_date
   , product
FROM example_table 
WHERE user_id = 1 
ORDER BY order_date ASC
```

| user_id | order_date | product |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 | A |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 | B |
| 1 | 2021-01-04 | A |
| 1 | 2021-01-07 | C |
| 1 | 2021-01-09 | C |
| 1 | 2021-01-20 | A |

Here's what I'm trying to achieve:

| user_id | order_date | product | cum_dist_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 | A | 1 |
| 1 | 2021-01-02 | B | 2 |
| 1 | 2021-01-04 | A | 2 |
| 1 | 2021-01-07 | C | 3 |
| 1 | 2021-01-09 | C | 3 |
| 1 | 2021-01-20 | A | 3 |

In other words, I want to be able to see how many unique items a customer has bough so far, and be able to see that for particular date (so for the example above: on 2021-01-04 they have bought 2 unique items and for 2021-01-07 that number was 3).

I've tried grouping by selecting user_id and product, and min(order_date) in a CTE, then doing ROW_NUMBER over user_id and product in that CTE and that worked partially - I'm able to seethe dates the countof unique products has changed (so for this example: 2021-01-01, 2021-01-02 and 2021-01-07, but then I loose the rows "between" which I still want to be able to access.

```
with cte as (
   SELECT 
      user_id
      , product
      , min(order_date) as first_order
   FROM example_table 
   GROUP BY 1,2
   ORDER BY order_date ASC
)

SELECT
   user_id
   , first_order
   , product
   , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id, product ORDER BY first_order) AS number_of_unique_products
WHERE user_id = 1
```

With the above, I would get:

| user_id | order_date | product | cum_dist_count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-01-01 | A | 1 |
| 1 | 2021-01-02 | B | 2 |
| 1 | 2021-01-07 | C | 3 |

The DB is in BigQuery StandardSQL.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For each item, you can record the earliest date it appears.  Then add those up:

```
select et.* except (seqnum),
       countif(seqnum = 1) over (partition by user_id order by order_date) as running_distinct_count
from (select et.*,
             row_number() over (partition by user_id, product order by order_date) as seqnum
      from example_table et
     ) et
```

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Below is for BigQuery

```
select * except(cum_products),
  (select count(distinct product) from t.cum_products product) as cum_dist_count
from (
    select *, 
      array_agg(product) over prev_rows as cum_products
    from example_table
    window prev_rows as (partition by user_id order by order_date)
) t
```

if applied to sample data in your question

```
with example_table as (
  select 1 user_id, '2021-01-01' order_date, 'A' product union all
  select 1, '2021-01-02', 'B' union all
  select 1, '2021-01-04', 'A' union all
  select 1, '2021-01-07', 'C' union all
  select 1, '2021-01-09', 'C' union all
  select 1, '2021-01-20', 'A' 
)
```

output is

[image]

Comment: did you have chance to try?